# What does IIS query string validation protect from?

Tags: iis, url

Recently we had a failure in one of our systems because IIS rejects query strings with (URL encoded) parameter values containing the sequence *&#*. It doesn't reject  *& #*.

We've got tired of working around this limitation  (e.g. user types a formula for a rule they want evaluated, we have to work around encoding less than and greater than signs, but I can't see a full list of things we are not allowed to have as a parameter, so every now and then a user can't do something legitimate because the request 500s).

We are considering turning it off completely ( setting [requestValidationMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode?view=netframework-4.8) to 0.0 ) but don't know what it's actually protecting us from.

Is the first one protecting against something important that is not triggered by the second? We don't put user inputs unencoded into HTML or intersperes them into SQL text or anything silly.